# Could not get a field value by reflection getter

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to filter a result set by a foreign key:

```
createCriteria(Person.class).add(Restrictions.ne("position", 1L)).list()
```

But getting this exception: `org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.example.model.Position.id`

Here are the necessary JPA entities (trimmed down to the necessary fields):

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @ForeignKey(name = "person_position_fkey")
    private Position position;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Position getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Position position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table
public class Position {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `Restrictions.ne("position.id", 1L)`

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. Can you provide it as an answer? So I can accept it.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try `Restrictions.ne("position.id", 1L)`

Comment: With an added explanation it would be even better